# What is the type of a field of a Scala class?

Tags: scala

I would like to write a function like the following:

```
def printFieldOfClass(field: ???) =
  println(field)
```

Suppose there is a case class definition such as `case class A(id: String)`. It would then be possible to call `printFieldOfClass(A.id)` which would print the string `"A.id"`. If we, however, try to call `printFieldOfClass(A.idd)`, I would want the code not to compile. Is this even possible? And if so, what is the type of the parameter `field`?

Help is much appreciated!

EDIT: As there seems to be some confusion about what I am trying to do, let me clarify: I do *not* want to pass *an instance* of the case class, I much rather want to pass a reference to some field in a class definition. Also I do not want my function to be hard wired to any such class, it should work with all Scala classes, like so: `printFieldOfClass(SomeClassTheFunctionDoesNotKnowAbout.someField)` should either print `"SomeClassTheFunctionDoesNotKnowAbout.someField"` in case `SomeClassTheFunctionDoesNotKnowAbout`'s definition specifies a field `someField` or, if the class has no such field, the call should not compile.

Comment: If the field does not exist, of course it's not going to compile. If the field exists, there's no way you your function can know where the value it gets as a parameter came from. Finally, doing such thing seems quite pointless.

Comment: By th way, if `A` is not a singleton, `A.field` wil never compile even if there's a field `field` on class `A`

Comment: I don't understand. Is it necessary for the function to know where the value it gets as a parameter came from? What do you mean with "came from"?

Comment: Just think about it. The method receives a value of any type. How could it possibly trace it back to a certain field of a certain class ? There's no way to do that, and that would not make sense to be able to do it

Comment: Use scala reflection.

Comment: @Dici In nearly every language, you would be correct. But Scala macros allow you to do this.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yeah, I knew about macros but I would honestly not be able to write one. I even fail to understand how that can be useful (I'm sure it can, but I haven't researched enough of what I consider to be an advanced feature of Scala). Thanks for you Scala answers, that's pretty good for learning stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible if `printFieldOfClass` is a normal method, as the comments explain. But you can make it a macro instead. It's basically a function which runs at compile-time, receives the syntax tree of its argument and generates a new tree to replace it. There are quite a few introductions to Scala macros, and writing another one in the answer doesn't make sense. But I don't advise trying it until you are very comfortable with Scala in general.

[An example](https://gist.github.com/dwickern/b47606a1ed2319afa6e2) which does something close to what you want:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Macros {
  def nameOfImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(x: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    @tailrec def extract(x: c.Tree): String = x match {
      case Ident(TermName(s)) => s
      case Select(_, TermName(s)) => s
      case Function(_, body) => extract(body)
      case Block(_, expr) => extract(expr)
      case Apply(func, _) => extract(func)
    }

    val name = extract(x)
    q"$name"
  }
  def nameOfMemberImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(f: c.Tree): c.Tree = nameOfImpl(c)(f)

  def nameOf(x: Any): String = macro nameOfImpl
  def nameOf[T](f: T => Any): String = macro nameOfMemberImpl
}

//
// Sample usage:
//

val someVariable = ""
Macros.nameOf(someVariable) // "someVariable"

def someFunction(x: Int): String = ???
Macros.nameOf(someFunction _) // "someFunction"

case class SomeClass(someParam: String)
val myClass = SomeClass("")
Macros.nameOf(myClass.someParam) // "someParam"

// without having an instance of the class:
Macros.nameOf[SomeClass](_.someParam) // "someParam"
```

Comment: What is `q` ? Could not find it here http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: @JensHoffmann oh I see, of course. It has to return a syntax tree, so this serves for the conversion. Thanks

Comment: Also, wasn't it posible to have a single `nameOfImpl` method ? Both your methods have the same implementation and signature.